# Alerting user between application event

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I'm not really sure how to describe the design issue I'm having so the title is very vague and possibly just totally wrong.

Basically, I have a web application which uses a number of different payment gateways, depending upon which one the user prefers.

Obviously the communication between the application and the gateway endpoint is going to be different for each. I need the way for my application to react to the response of the gateway by the means of a javascript alert (for now). The gateways might have different return url's back to the application, and it needs to work between browser sessions.

Any ideas or pointers to technology that will help with this?

If it helps the technology stack im using: Java, Spring, Struts

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a dedicated messaging layer with Redis, Socket.io or Rabbit.mq. I had the same issue with a medical app. If you want to stick to Java i would recommend an Observer pattern to pass event messages between classes but you still need a way to distribute notifications to the presentation layer handlers (Javascript) and thats were I recommend a socket server of sorts